# Autohotkey script - Combining two keypresses into one

Tags: autohotkey

I have a question regarding combining two key presses

> Alt and `

into one key press

> `

I have tried to fiddle around and search for some similar examples but none have worked for me unfortunately!

I want to have my script hold down the Alt key (RAlt preferably) and then press

> `

once (backtick character - usually located on the same key as the tilde). It triggers a menu in a certain game which used to be accessible by just pressing ` one time.

I've tried the following code segment but it doesn't work.

```
    `::
    KeyWait RAlt
    Send, {`}
    Return
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You want pressing ` to instead press `Alt` + ` ? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Yes that's correct - my post seems messy because coincidentally the ` character is used for formatting in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as mapping the keys like this:

```
`::!`
```

If you really would like to use the <kbd>RAlt</kbd> specifically:

```
`::Send {RAlt Down}{``}{RAlt Up}
```

Comment: This is 95% working, thanks! I just have one problem - it produces a ` character in a chatbox upon closing the interface. Ex: I hit the ` key once, it opens the menu like how I wanted it to but the same key is used to minimize the menu. Pressing it a second time does in fact close the menu however it produces an unwanted "`". Any idea how this could be prevented?

Comment: Does simply pressing Alt minimize the menu? That would be the only reason I would think the character would be sent like that.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't minimize it. Another person who I spoke to had came up with the same code and had the same problem. Still trying to figure it out.